# jQuery Datetimepicker doesnt update value

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Datetimepicker library shows only now() date but in input value is another date.

```js
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
          format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
          locale: 'de',
          daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type='text' class="form-control date-picker" name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" value="24.10.2017" required="required">
```

And even value of my input element is 24.10.2017 I can see only date from today (now()) -> 20.10.2017.

I have tried with `$('#delivery_date').datetimepicker('refresh');` but result is the same

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: @Master Yoda I have solved problem using $("#delivery_date").val(deliveryDate); after page is loaded... its not clean solution but it works

Comment: So it turned out to be an issue with page load? No problem at least you got sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the following [plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

In your example you use the `Format` option, `jQuery-ui` **requires** the `dateFormat` option. You also want to input dates in format *day/month/year* so I rearranged your date formatting as `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`

I also set your time format to 24hr format using `timeFormat: 'HH:mm'`

You need to **include the time** in your input value so that `datetimepicker` can pick it up. In the example below I set the time to default 00:00.

```js
$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
  locale: 'de',
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type='text' class="form-control date-picker" name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" value="24/10/2017 00:00" required="required">
```